# Adding multiple Date Fields in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add a field that would let me add multiple show dates in a Django Model. Sometimes the show date will contain 3 dates, sometimes 1 or sometimes 7. How am I able to add this in a model and have it so I can add multiple dates in the Django admin?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using postgres you can use an `ArrayField` for this purpose.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateTimeField(),
    )
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

An alternate approach would be to declare a `ShowDate` model and set a `ForeignKey` linking back to your `Show` model.